# Multiple counts in Sparql query

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I would like to create a Sparql query that contains two counts.

The query should get the 'neighbours of neighbours' of A (A → B → C, where A is the start node), and should report for each C, how many paths there were from A to C, and how many "inlinks" there are to C from anywhere. The result set should be as follow:

```
C | #C |  C_INLINKS
--------------------------
A | 2  | 123
B | 3  | 234
```

Where #C is the number of paths to C from starting node A.

I can create the counts separately, but I don't know how to combine these:

[**Count neighbours of neighbours:**](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fc%20count%28%3Fc%29%20as%20%3Fcountc%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAFC_Ajax%3E%20%3Fp1%20%3Fb.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fb%20%3Fp2%20%3Fc.%0D%0A%20%20%20FILTER%20%28regex%28str%28%3Fc%29%2C%20%27%5Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%27%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fc%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fcountc%29%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```sql
select ?c count(?c) as ?countc WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/AFC_Ajax> ?p1 ?b.
   ?b ?p2 ?c.
   FILTER (regex(str(?c), '^http://dbpedia.org/resource/'))
}
GROUP BY ?c
ORDER BY DESC(?countc)
LIMIT 100
```

[**Count inlinks to neighbours of neigbours**](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%3Fc+count%28%3Finlink%29+as+%3Finlinks+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAFC_Ajax%3E+%3Fp1+%3Fb.%0D%0A+++%3Fb+%3Fp2+%3Fc.%0D%0A+++%3Finlink+%3Fp3+%3Fc%0D%0A+++FILTER+%28regex%28str%28%3Fc%29%2C+%27%5Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%27%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fc%0D%0AORDER+BY+DESC%28%3Finlinks%29%0D%0ALIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```sql
select ?c count(?inlink) as ?inlinks WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/AFC_Ajax> ?p1 ?b.
   ?b ?p2 ?c.
   ?inlink ?p3 ?c
   FILTER (regex(str(?c), '^http://dbpedia.org/resource/'))
}
GROUP BY ?c
ORDER BY DESC(?inlinks)
LIMIT 100
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counts you're trying to extract require you to **group by** different things.  **group by** lets you specify what you're trying to count with respect to.  E.g., when you say, **select (count(?x) as ?xn) {...} group by ?y**, you're saying "how many ?x's appear *per each value* of ?y.   The counts you're looking for are: "how many C's per A" and then "how many inlinks per C"?  That means that in one case you'd need to **group by ?a** and in the other, you'd need to **group by ?c**.  However, in this case, since you've got a fixed **?a**, this might be a little bit easier.  To count the distinct paths (?p1,?p2) is a little bit tricky, since when you do **count(distinct …)**, you can only have a single expression for **…**.  However, you can be sneaky by counting distinct **concat(str(?p1),str(?p2))**, which is a single expression, and should be unique for each ?p1 ?p2 pair.  Then I think you'd be looking for a query like this:

```sql
select ?c
       (count(distinct concat(str(?p1),str(?b),str(?p2))) as ?n_paths)
       (count(distinct ?inlink) as ?n_inlink)
where {
  dbpedia:AFC_Ajax ?p1 ?b . ?b ?p2 ?c .
  ?inlink ?p ?c
  filter strstarts(str(?c),str(dbpedia:))
}
group by ?c
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fc%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28count%28distinct%20concat%28str%28%3Fp1%29%2Cstr%28%3Fb%29%2Cstr%28%3Fp2%29%29%29%20as%20%3Fn_paths%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28count%28distinct%20%3Finlink%29%20as%20%3Fn_inlink%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AAFC_Ajax%20%3Fp1%20%3Fb%20.%20%3Fb%20%3Fp2%20%3Fc%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Finlink%20%3Fp%20%3Fc%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fc%29%2Cstr%28dbpedia%3A%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fc%0D%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3Fn_paths%29&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
c                                                           n_paths n_inlink
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://dbpedia.org/resource/AFC_Ajax                        32      540
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:AFC_Ajax_players       17      484
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Living_people          17      659447
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Eredivisie_players     13      2232
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Dutch_footballers      12      2141
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:1994_births             6      3605
…
```

Comment: Hi, I have  a feeling it still does not return the correct values. For example, using select distinct ?p1,?b,?p2
where {
  dbpedia:AFC_Ajax ?p1 ?b . ?b ?p2 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:AFC_Ajax_players>
}

I find there are 57 paths between AFC_Ajax and Category:AFC_Ajax_players. But your query gives 17. I don't understand why these number are different. Do you know what is going wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: It seems that if I remove a "count()" the other count() values also changes, but that doesn't make sense right? Because the values are grouped on ?c.